# Format a time Hh:mm:ss Z in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Currently I have a date time that comes in the format "12:00 PM" or "9 AM" for example. I need to get this time in the format `Hh:mm:ss Z`.  I have access to moment.js, but I'm not sure how to make this formatting transition. Thoughts?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [moment.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for this

```js
var momentObj = moment("12:00 PM", ["h:mm A"])
var momentObj1 = moment("9:00 AM", ["h:mm A"])
document.getElementById("output").innerText = momentObj.format("hh:mm:ss Z") + "\n"+ momentObj1.format("hh:mm:ss Z");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This will create a valid date
`var time = moment("12:00 PM", "h:mm A");`

Then you can parse it as you wish
`time.format("h:mm:ss")` which displays "12:00:00"
`time.format("h:mm:ss Z")` which displays "12:00:00 -06:00"

For more formats and docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/